# Is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle limited to measurements in the same direction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle follows from the commutational relationship between the position and momentum operators, namely: $[\hat x_i,\hat p_j]=i\hbar\delta_{ij}$. Of course, in one dimension, this is simply $[\hat x, \hat p]=i\hbar$; but what about measuring two different directions, say $\hat x_1$ and $\hat p_2$? In this case, the operators actually commute.

I got the following result using David Tong's reasoning for the Uncertainty Principle, found in his QM lectures section 3.4. I simply changed the fact that, now, the operators commute, and therefore:

$$ (\Delta_{\psi}x_1)(\Delta_{\psi}p_2)\geq 0$$

This doesn't necessarily imply that both uncertainties *have* to be zero, but it shows that they *can* be. Is this correct? Does the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle only work for position and momentum measurements along the same axis?

EDIT: [Link to the lectures, if anyone wants to follow the reasoning](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/quantum.html).

Comment: "In this case, the operators actually commute."  You've answered your question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There is a generalized Heisenberg uncertainty principle for two observables $A$ and $B$ is given by

$$\Delta A \Delta B \geq \frac{1}{2} |\langle \psi |[A,B]|\psi\rangle |$$

where $[A,B]=AB-BA$ the commutator. If you use position and momentum in the same direction $[x_j,p_j]=\mathrm i \hbar$ ($j\in\{1,2,3\}$), you recover the usual Heisenberg uncertainty relation.

Now all you have to ask is what is $[x_i,p_j]$ for $i\neq j$ (position/momentum operators in two different Cartesian axes). The answer is $[x_i,p_j]=0$. That means that you can find a common basis for the position $x_i$ and momentum $p_j$ ($i\neq j$) where the basis states have defined values of $x_i$ and $p_i$ at the same time.

Similarly, you have $[x_i,x_j]=0$ and $[p_i,p_j]=0$.

For other operators this relation is even more complicated. For example for angular momentum operators you have

$$\Delta L_x \Delta L_y \geq \frac{1}{2}|\langle\psi| L_z|\psi\rangle|$$.

Answer (score 0):

Per your example, consider:

$$\psi(x, y, z, t) = \frac 1 N e^{i(p/\hbar -\omega t)}\delta(x)\delta(z) $$

In the $y$ coordinate, it's an eigenstate of momentum:

$$\hat p_y\psi = p\psi $$

while in the other coordinates, it has maximal momentum uncertainty and definite position (if the delta functions bother you, feel free to use a Gaussian limit).

Since $\sigma_{p_y} = 0$, you will always have:

$$ \sigma_{p_y}\sigma_x = 0 $$

no matter what the $x$ of $z$ dependence is.